# Sharepoint 2019 On Premise PIcture Gallery not showing up when adding a webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

A Picture Gallery(Slide Show) was created via "Add an app" on the SharePoint site where it is to be placed.  I see it in site contents (as a Picture Library) but when I go to add it on the page (add a webpart in column...) it is not available in the list. Any direction is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Whether you want to add picture library on the classic page or modern page?

1.Add picture library on the classic page. Edit page -> Insert Web Part -> Apps -> picture library.

2.Add picture library on the modern page. Edit page -> Document library web part -> Choose picture library.